# How to hide a row / section based on selected value with Eureka framework

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I have try to create a survey form by using `Eureka framework`. However, how to hide a section when the specific option has been choose?

Please help!

```
let fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"]

form +++= SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>() { section in
    section.header = HeaderFooterView(title: "What is your favorite fruit ?")
}

for fruit in fruits {
    form.last! <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(fruit) { lrow in
        lrow.title = fruit
        lrow.selectableValue = fruit
    }
}

form +++ Section("xxxxxx Question") {
    //hide this section when apple is selected
    //$0.hidden =
}

form.last! <<< TextAreaRow() {
    $0.title = "Enter description here..."
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by setting a tag for your fruits section, like "fruits_section". Then you can set the hidden variable like this:

```
$0.hidden = Condition.Function([]) 
            { form in
                if let section = form.sectionByTag("fruits_section") as? SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String> {
                    if section.selectedRow()?.title == "Apple" {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
```

To force this hidden condition to be evaluated when a row is selected in the first section you can use the `onSelectSelectableRow` of the first section:

```
(section as! SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>).onSelectSelectableRow = { [weak self] _ in
     self?.form.sectionByTag("last_section_tag")?.evaluateHidden()
}
```

Do not forget to set the correct tag for both sections.

Instead of using tags you can use `form.first` and `form.last` if you have just two sections, but it is not recommended.

Comment: Hi Mathias Claassen, thanks for your reply. Can you assist me in another question? Thanks.

Comment: The second piece of code that you write, where does it have to be inside the Form ???